# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'NoneType' in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error? I'm really new and I'd appreciate someone's help. This is my code:

```
import turtle as t
import math as m
import random as r

raindrops = int(input("Enter the number of raindrops: "))

def drawSquare():
    t.up()
    t.goto(-300,-300)
    t.down()
    t.fd(600)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(600)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(600)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(600)
    t.lt(90)

def location():
    x = (r.randint(-300, 300))
    y = (r.randint(-300, 300))
    t.up()
    t.goto(x, y)
    return x, y

def drawRaindrops(x, y):
    t.fillcolor(r.random(), r.random(), r.random())
    circles = (r.randint(3, 8))
    radius = (r.randint(1, 20))
    newradius = radius
    area = 0
    t.up()
    t.rt(90)
    t.fd(newradius)
    t.lt(90)
    t.down()
    t.begin_fill()
    t.circle(newradius)
    t.end_fill()
    t.up()
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(newradius)
    t.rt(90)
    while circles > 0:
        if x + newradius < 300 and x - newradius > -300 and y + newradius < 300 and y - newradius > -300:
            t.up()
            t.rt(90)
            t.fd(newradius)
            t.lt(90)
            t.down()
            t.circle(newradius)
            t.up()
            t.lt(90)
            t.fd(newradius)
            t.rt(90)
            newradius += radius
            circles -= 1
            area += m.pi * radius * radius
        else:
            circles -= 1
    return area

def promptRaindrops(raindrops):
    if raindrops < 1 or raindrops > 100:
        print ("Raindrops must be between 1 and 100 inclusive.")
    if raindrops >= 1 and raindrops <= 100:
        x, y = location()
        area = drawRaindrops(x, y)
        area += promptRaindrops(raindrops - 1)
        return x, y, area

def main():
    t.speed(0)
    drawSquare()
    x, y, area = promptRaindrops(raindrops)
    print('The area is:', area, 'square units.')

main()
t.done()
```

I'm assuming something is wrong with the "+=" but I have no idea what. I'm fairly certain that the area is correctly being returned. Help please. :)

Comment: Your function `promptRaindrops` has 2 paths through it. When it takes the first one it fails to return anything, therefore the default return of `None` is used. It should always return the same type, otherwise do something to indicate an error externally like throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I noticed:

## 1. `promptRaindrops` returns a tuple

I am sure you didn't intend this, but when you say `area += promptRaindrops(raindrops - 1)`, you are adding a *tuple* to `area`, which is an *integer*. To fix this, you should say `area += promptRaindrops(raindrops - 1)[2]` to get the area returned. However, your error is generated by

## 2. Your base case doesn't return a value

In `promptRaindrops`, you return a recursive call of the function whenever `1 <= raindrops <= 100`. But, when it is outside that range, it returns nothing, only prints a message. Your function will **always** be outside of that range, because if you keep decreasing the value passed in to `promptRaindrops`, it will eventually go below 1. When it does, you return `None` (since you didn't return anything). That `None` bubbles up through every single recursion call made to that point, and you will inevitably be adding `None` to `area`. Add a return statement returning a tuple, and your error should vanish.

Answer (score 0):

In `promptRaindrops()` you perform a `+=` operation with a *recursive call* to `promptRaindrops()` which will **not** return anything (`NoneType`) if `raindrops` is outside the given range.

Depending on how the program should behave, either something should be returned there or it should not be called with values outside the given range.

Comment: You can't avoid calling the function outside the range; subtracting the passed value will eventually go below 1.

Comment: Of course you can, with a simple condition on the input argument before calling the function. This would defeat the whole purpose of a recursive function, but I just wanted to point towards any possible solution to the question at hand.